# Repeat last command in MongoDB console?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu, mongodb

I am using Ubuntu.  From the mongo console I want to repeat the last command so I can modify it before executing it again, same way as I would if I was in the bash Terminal.  Normally, I would press the up arrow for this, but instead I get a few random characters.  Likewise, I would normally press the home key to go to the beginning of the line but instead I get a few random characters.  Any ideas on how to make the console behave normally?  Perhaps there are alternative function keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds weird. Did you install from the mongodb repo, or the default ubuntu/debian one? You should install a current version if you haven't (1.6.5+), using the mongodb repositories.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

The up/down array stuff is handled by the readline library. Is it possible that you have a problem there? Please check to make sure you have it installed.

Comment: Indeed. I had similar problems, but they're gone after I installed recent version from the mongodb repo.

Comment: I installed using Synaptic Package Manager.  Thanks for the tip.